# HornetQ embedded Cluster Configuration

Tags: hornetq

I am trying to start an embedded cluster configuration but I wasn't able to do so. 
I used the cluster example that was found on the hornetq examples. It works, I aren't to run the examples using an embedded hornetq. I can't get any exception but the system dies.

```
public class HornetQEmbedded  {

    private JMSServerManager jmsServerManager;

    public HornetQEmbedded() {
    }


    public void start() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting Embedded HornetQ instance...");

            // Retrieve configuration from xml file
            FileConfiguration configuration = new FileConfiguration();
            configuration.setConfigurationUrl("hornetq-configuration.xml");
            configuration.start();

            // Change acceptor configuration
            Map<String, Object> acceptorParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            acceptorParams.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, "5446");
            acceptorParams.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "0.0.0.0");
            configuration.getAcceptorConfigurations().clear();
            configuration.getAcceptorConfigurations().add(new   TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), acceptorParams));


            // Change connector configuration
            Map<String, Object> connectorParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            connectorParams.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, "5446");
            connectorParams.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "0.0.0.0");
            configuration.getConnectorConfigurations().clear();
            configuration.getConnectorConfigurations().put("netty", new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), connectorParams));

            // Create HornetQ server
            HornetQServer server = HornetQServers.newHornetQServer(configuration);
            server.getSecurityManager().addUser("guest", "guest");
            server.getSecurityManager().setDefaultUser("guest");
            server.getSecurityManager().addRole("guest", "guest");


            // Load queues
            jmsServerManager = new JMSServerManagerImpl(server, "hornetq-jms.xml");
            jmsServerManager.setContext(null);               

            // Start server
            jmsServerManager.start();

            System.out.println("Waiting 5 second for embedded hornetq server to start...");
            Thread.sleep(5000);           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error starting Embedded HornetQ server: " + e.toString());           
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }       
}
```

And this is the HornetQ configuration file:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">

   <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>   
   <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>   
   <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>   
   <journal-min-files>10</journal-min-files>   
   <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>   
   <connectors>
      <connector name="netty">
         <factory-    class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:0.0.0.0}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5444}"/>
      </connector>
   </connectors>

   <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="netty">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:0.0.0.0}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5446}"/>
      </acceptor>
   </acceptors>

   <!-- Clustering configuration -->

   <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
         <group-address>127.0.0.1</group-address> <!-- 231.7.7.7  -->
         <group-port>5442</group-port> <!-- 9876 -->
         <broadcast-period>100</broadcast-period>
         <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
      </broadcast-group>
   </broadcast-groups>

   <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
         <group-address>127.0.0.1</group-address> <!-- 231.7.7.7  -->
         <group-port>5442</group-port>  <!-- 9876 -->
         <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
   </discovery-groups>

   <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
         <address>jms</address>
         <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
         <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
         <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
         <forward-when-no-consumers>true</forward-when-no-consumers>
         <max-hops>1</max-hops>
         <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
      </cluster-connection>
   </cluster-connections>

   <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
         <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
         <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
      </security-setting>
   </security-settings>

   <address-settings>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
         <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
         <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
         <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
         <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
         <max-size-bytes>209715200</max-size-bytes>       
         <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
         <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
      </address-setting>
   </address-settings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I would need to see some code.. why don't you edit your question with some code to verify what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Added the code and the hornetq configuration

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? you didn't either accept it or commented it. Let me know if you still need help

Answer (score 2):

The example was written thinking on the embedded use case.. The server will live as part of your application. What means as long as your VM dies, the server will die.

On an embedded server, you are supposed to start a thread and leave it running.

As a hack now, try adding a sleep at the end of your start, but then make your proper application with a proper life cycle.